# Reading jsonObject as MyClass<T> using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to use Gson to parse a json object which contains a `result` which can be of some given classes which I already am able to parse normally. I am defining the `ResultResponse` class like this:

```
public class ResultResponse<T>
{
    @SerializedName("result")
    public T Response;
}
```

And I want to read it like:

```
ResultResponse<NewTypeResponse> result = new Gson().fromJson(response, ResultResponse.class);
```

But I believe this is not the correct way to do this. I am getting this warning as well:

> Unchecked assignment: 'rs.test.ResultResponse' to 'rs.test.ResultResponse

I am looking for the correct way to do this. Any helpful answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a concrete `T` (and I assume `NewTypeResponse` is such one and not just dummy code), you can use a [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to tell Gson about a generic type like this:

```
ResultResponse<NewTypeResponse> result = new Gson().fromJson(response,
    new TypeToken<ResultResponse<NewTypeResponse>>() {}.getType());
```

This creates a new anonymous class extending `TypeToken` which captures the full type of `ResultResponse<NewTypeResponse>`, making it accessible to Gson at runtime.

There's some documentation on TypeToken in the Gson docs: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types